# Problemas ao publicar uma aplicação em asp.net no IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deploy

Estou tentando publicar minha aplicação num servidor windows server 2012 com IIS 8. FIz o passo a passo de ir em "Site -> Add Website" preencher com as coordenadas, caminhos e etc. Fiz o deploy na devida pasta padrão "Inetpub -> wwwroot", porém obtenho os seguintes erros ao testar no browse do próprio servidor ou acessar a url de fora pela minha intranet.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo Chrome

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ambos acima eu estou usando pelo IIS a 'Authentication = Disabled'. 
Quando passo para 'Authentication = Enabled' esse é o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu webconfig está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Competências.Business.CustomRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />


<globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>

<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

E minha connectionstring:

```
public const string CONNECTION_STRING = @"Data Source=XXXXXX;Initial Catalog=Competências;User Id=integracao;Password=XXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
 public const string DEVELOPMENT_CONNECTION_STRING = @"Data Source=XXXXXX;Initial Catalog=Competências;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
```

O que está faltando configurar corretamente para conseguir publicar minha aplicação?

Answer (score 1):

O problema acusado pela página de erro é que o usuário está em branco. Veja a mensagem:

```
Login failed for user ''
```

As aspas simples no final da mensagem, indica o nome do usuário que está sendo enviado.

Em sua string de conexão `DEVELOPMENT_CONNECTION_STRING`, você utiliza a segurança integrada com o windows. Quando você modificou a autenticação para enabled=true, muito provavelmente você permitiu autenticação anônima no IIS.

Para corrigir, adicione a configuração a seguir no web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

Essa configuração fará com que o IIS identifique o usuário que está acessando o seu site e repasse esse usuário para a autenticação no banco de dados.

Precauções: você deve estudar a melhor forma de autenticar os usuário que acessarão esse site. Se é um site intranet, talvez esse tipo de autenticação seja a melhor forma, caso contrário, aconselho a você a procurar alguns padrões de autenticação para ASP.NET.

Mais informações de como modificar o modo de autenticação do IIS, veja neste artigo na [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: acrescentei o código sugerido @anmaia no webconfig. Agora o erro é **Login failed for user 'Dominio\servidordoIIS$'.**

Comment: O que vc deve fazer e configurar o seu pool de aplicação para utilizar o usuário do Windows também. Muito provavelmente está utilizando o LocalSystem, vc deve mudar a identidade para ApplicationPoolIdentity, veja se [esse link](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) lhe ajuda.

Comment: Já havia checado isso... Estava ApplicationPoolIdentity já.